# What are some common data augmentation techniques used for code?

Tags: data-augmentation

I understand that there are data augmentation techniques for natural language such as word/sentence shuffling, word replacement with synonyms and syntax-tree manipulation.

However, I have hard time finding data augmentation techniques for code snippets(e.g. java, c++, etc).

For example, natural language (e.g. I am a human) and code snippet (e.g.  def function(foo): print(foo)) have quite different syntactic and semantic characteristics. Thus, I don't think the data augmentation techniques for natural language (e.g. word replacement with synonyms) can be applied to code snippets.

Could someone tell me what are some common data augmentation used for code?
Thank you.

Comment: I cant follow what this means. Can you give more context?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I updated the post with more details. Thank you.